# Avoiding recursive loop when saving a task

Tags: php, recursion

So I am trying to check if a recursion is happening when saving a task/job.
The task can have a setting called "next_job" which indicates which job needs to be triggered right away after this one is finished.
There can be many jobs, so i need to take care no loops get created. A job can also be saved with an empty or not defined next_job setting.

`getJobsFromDatabase` is only a function returning an array of objects.
One example element would be:

```
['id => 1, 'title' => 'some job', 'next_job' => 3]
```

So this is a simplified version of what I have tried:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->jobs = [];
}

public function onSave($data)
{
    $next_job_id = (int) $data['next_job'];
    if ($next_job_id > 0 && $this->checkLoop($data)) {
        $this->error('Loop happening');
        return false;
    }
  
    return $data;
}

private function checkLoop($data)
{
    $visited = [];
    $stack = [];

    $jobs = $db->getJobsFromDatabase();

    foreach ($jobs as $job) {
        $this->jobs[$job->id] = $job;
    }

    // $data is the job being saved right now
    $job = $this->jobs[$data['id']];

    // check if currently saved job creates a recursion
    if ($this->checkLoopRecursive($job->id, $visited, $stack)) {
        echo "> REKURSIVE";

        return true;
    }
    echo "> NO REKURSION";

    return false;
}

private function checkLoopRecursive($job_id, &$visited, &$stack)
{
    if (!isset($visited[$job_id])) {

        $visited[$job_id] = true;
        $stack[$job_id] = true;

        $next_job_id = (int) $this->jobs[$job_id]->next_job;

        // this is not working
        // if ($next_job_id === 0) {
        //     $stack[$job_id] = false;
        //     return false;
        // }

        if ($next_job_id !== 0) {
            if (!isset($visited[$next_job_id]) && $this->checkLoopRecursive($next_job_id, $visited, $stack)) {

                return true;
            } elseif (isset($stack[$next_job_id])) {

                return true;
            }
        }

    }
    $stack[$job_id] = false;

    return false;
}
```

Whenever there is no next job (ZERO) I also get a recursion.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Calls like `getJobsFromDatabase` aren't defined. How are you invoking these functions? Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Are you trying to check if the current node creates a loop, or are you trying to check for loops anywhere along the linked list?

Comment: @RobEyre trying to check only for the currently created task/job.

Comment: So I guess you could simplify things, just by searching for the id of the current node in the linked list that follows it, correct?

Comment: i tried that, but if the current job is being called by another job, that is not working. So i guess my first answer was wrong.

Comment: Honestly I would just have something like `if( in_array($job->id, $this->seen) ) { /* handle recursion */ } else { $this->seen[] = $job->id; }` to check as I go. You would only need to pre-walk the job structure if the presence of a recursion is supposed to invalidate the _entire_ run before it even starts, rather than just avoiding entering an endless loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might get better performance by simply following the linked list, looking for the id of the job you want to test.  If you find it again, anywhere in the list, then you have a recursive loop - otherwise not.

Furthermore, if you have many jobs in your list, you could end up with running out of stack space if you take a recursive approach.  I suggest a simple process that 'walks' the linked list, looking for the original id.

```
class RecursionChecker
{
    protected $jobs = [];

    public function __construct($db)
    {
        $jobs = $db->getJobsFromDatabase();
        foreach ($jobs as $job) {
            $this->jobs[$job->id] = $job;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check for recursion
     * returns true if the job is in a recursive loop, false otherwise
     */
    public function checkJobId($jobId): bool
    {
        if (!$jobId || !array_key_exists($jobId, $this->jobs)) {
            // missing or invalid job id
            return false;
        }

        // initialise the loop
        $contextJobId = $jobId;

        do {
            $nextJobId = $this->jobs[$contextJobId]->next_job;
            if (!$nextJobId || !array_key_exists($nextJobId, $this->jobs)) {
                // end of list, or invalid next_job id
                return false;
            }
            if ($nextJobId == $jobId) {
                // found recursion
                return true;
            }

            // move to considering the next node in the list
            $contextJobId = $nextJobId;

        } while (true); 
    }
}
```

Comment: you are probably right. will reduce the idea a bit. thanks!